# How to connect to a ftp server in react-native?

Tags: react-native, ftp

I want to write a react-native project that supports downloading and uploading files. 
Now I'm using react-native-ftp package. But I don't know how to **create a new directory** in ftp server with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You would use some backend APIs that will connect to FTP on react behalf. Like List, Add, Update, Rename etc..

Comment: sure, but do I need to create those APIs myself? I don't know...X﹏X .